# Migrate Wix Toolset projects to InstallShield

Tags: wix, windows-installer, migration, installshield

There are several resources around the web (including here) for migrating InstallShield projects to WiX Toolset, and it's understandable (move from costly product to a free one).

However, I couldn't find anything about the opposite direction - suppose there are several WiX Toolset projects which we want to move into InstallShield (due to issues with WiX licensing). True, we can go ahead and rewrite the projects, but the risk of losing or misinterpreting something is high.

Before we start to develop some sort of automated migration script, I was wondering if it has done before, have anyone ever heard of such a thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

InstallShield does not have a .wxs importer. However hidden in the File > Open dialog, in the drop down part of the Open button, is the option to Open with Wizard (or, I believe, Open As > Wizard in earlier versions). You can use this to convert a built .msi file into a project file. However if you want it to be a *good* project file, you will likely still have to perform significant clean up. And be aware that minor upgrades or patches are likely to be difficult or impossible across this tool change.

I don't recall whether this option is available in the InstallShield automation interface, but I think I would prefer to convert and vet each project by hand anyway.

Comment: Good point about patches! You are probably right, it will require manual intervention anyway, so converting by hand seems the logical choice.